# How to display a row of the total sum when the date is changed?

Tags: html, postgresql, jsp, jstl

I am displaying historical connexions of users, that is showing the connexion datetime and deconnexion datetime and the duration of the connexion, for each user. In my query I already get the sum of the durations by date :

```
...
String sql = "select TRIM(e.nomemploye) || CASE WHEN e.nomemploye IS NULL OR TRIM(e.nomemploye) = '' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END || e.prenomemploye as user, " + 
                "to_char(h.connexion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as connex, " + 
                "to_char(h.deconnexion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as deconnex, " + 
                "to_char(CAST(h.duree_seconde || ' second' AS INTERVAL), 'HH24:MI:SS') as duree, " + 
                "to_char(CAST(SUM(h.duree_seconde) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(h.connexion AS DATE)) || ' second' AS INTERVAL), 'HH24:MI:SS') duree_totale_par_date " + 
                "from employe e join utilisateur u on e.idemploye = u.idemploye " +
                "join histodureeconnexion h on h.iduser = u.idutilisateur ";
...
```

As you can see there is the `duree_totale_par_date` alias which calculates the sum of the connexion duration by date.

Now I want to display the rows in JSP :

```
...
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="histoDureeConnexController">
...
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Utilisateur</th>
           <th>Date de connexion</th>
           <th>Date de déconnexion</th>
           <th>Durée de connexion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="histoDureeConnex in histoDureeConnexs">
           <td>{{histoDureeConnex.user}}</td>
           <td>{{histoDureeConnex.connex}}</td>
           <td>{{histoDureeConnex.deconnex == 'null' ? 'Session encore ouverte' : histoDureeConnex.deconnex}}</td>
           <td>{{histoDureeConnex.duree == 'null' ? '' : histoDureeConnex.duree}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
...
</div>
```

What I want is to display a row for the `duree_totale_par_date` column below a user row when the date changes for a user; something like this :

[image]

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Do you want to add a row or another column with the data you're looking to display? Another column I thought would have made more sense, otherwise you end up with a staggered table that will not look uniform.

Comment: I want to add a row with the total sum